# Elasticsearch: document size and query performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index with medium size documents (15-30 Mb more or less).

Each document has a boolean field and most of the times users just want to know if a specific document ID has that field set to true.

Will document size affect the performance of this query?

```
   "size": 1,
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "my_field": True
      }
   },
   "_source": [
      "my_field"
   ]
```

And will a "size":0 query results in better time performance?

Comment: Shouldn't you use "fields" instead of "_source"?
BTW. both jordivador advices in his answer should help in performance.
If you have the index just make tests to be sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `"size":0` to your query, you will avoid some net transfer this behaviour will improve your performance time.

But as I understand your case of use, you can use [count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

An example query:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_count -d '{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": xxxxx
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "bool_field": True
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }'
```

With this query only checking if there is some total, you will know if a doc with some id have set the bool field to true/false depending on the value that you specify in bool_field at query. This will be quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Elasticsearch will index your fields, the document size will not be a big problem for the performance. Using size 0 don't affect the query performance inside Elasticsearch but affect positively the performance to retrieve the document because the network transfer.

If you just want to check one boolean field for a specific document you can simply use [Get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) to obtain the document just retrieving the field you want to check, like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1000?fields=my_field'
```

In this case Elasticsearch will just retrieve the document with `_id = 1000` and the field `my_field`. So you can check the boolean value.

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "my_type",
  "_id": "1000",
  "_version": 9,
  "found": true,
  "fields": {
    "my_field": [
      true
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question I see that you haven't mentioned the elasticsearch version you are using. I would say there are lot of factors that affects the performance of a elasticsearch cluster.

However assuming it is the latest elasticsearch and considering that you are after a single value, the best approach is to change your query in to a non-scoring, filtering query. Filters are quite fast in elasticsearch and very easily cached. Making a query non-scoring avoids the scoring phase entirely(calculating relevance, etc...).

To to this:

```
GET localhost:9200/test_index/test_partition/_search
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : { 
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { 
                "my_field" : True
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note that we are using the search API. The constant_score is used to convert the term query in to a filter, which should be inherently fast.

For more information. Please refer [Finding exact values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)